# copy one letter from a string into another

Tags: c, string, copy, character

So I need to create a function that copies the characters from the even position of one string into a dynamically create new string and then return the new string. If I send the function "ABCDEFG" it returns "ACEG". How do you copy one character of a string into a new one in C? I tried the strcpy function, but it just printed the whole string.

```
    char * str(char *s1){
    int i;
    char *s2;
    s2 = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char ));
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(s1); i++){
        if(i % 2 == 0){
            ///copy from s1 to s2
            printf("s2: %s", s2);   
        }
    }
    return s2;
    }
```

Comment: "How do I assign the value from one variable to another?" - So what did you not understand from your C book? Or from a simple search?

Comment: Derefence them, of course. If you don't know this, step back in your book and read the chapter about pointers or ask your teacher.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use [strcat()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcat.htm) function available in C. You don't need to copy char from s1 to s2 instead append the required characters as string from s1 to string s2. This is enough hint to solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: OP wants to copy **single characters**! `strcat` is wrong for that.

Comment: My bad I have written it as string. That was a typo. I changed it.